# Why my .pagnation li add active did not work for page 1?

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

My pagination for page 1 did not activated. however, it does active for other pages.

Not sure where had gone wrong.

Also dont really understand why `$i+1` works. I just try my luck when `$page == $i` does not work.

This is my page 1, where it does not seem to work
[image: Page 1]

This is my page 2, which is working fine. The same for other pages. Only page 1 is not working
[image]

When i tried `if ($page == $i+1 || $page == 1)`.
[image]

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
echo"<div align='center'>  
        <ul class='pagination'>";
        $activeOrNotClass = "";
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]) / 4 + 1; $i++) {

            echo"<li class='$activeOrNotClass'><a href='collectionPage.php?cat={$catCode}&page={$i}'> {$i}</a></li>
         ";
            echo"page:$page"; // i used to check my page value
            echo"i = $i"; // i used to check my $i value
            if ($page == $i+1){ 
            $activeOrNotClass = "active";}else{
                    $activeOrNotClass = "";
                }
            }

        echo"<li><a href='collectionSummary.php?cat={$catCode}'>view all</a></li>";

        echo"</ul>
        </div>";
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, your `if ($page == $i+1){` is never going to be true for the first page. Perhaps if you add `|| $page == 1` this would solve your problem.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I tried that before. still not working. I also tried to add else if but still fails.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas The OP is setting the `$activeOrNotClass` **after** they echo the current link/li, so the page 1 will never work no matter what they check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing your link/`li` **before** you set your `$activeOrNotClass`, which is why it does not work for `page=1`. You need to swap the order of your code, and use `$page == $i`

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]) / 4 + 1; $i++) {
        if ($page == $i){ 
            $activeOrNotClass = "active";
        } else{
            $activeOrNotClass = "";
        }
        echo"<li class='$activeOrNotClass'><a href='collectionPage.php?cat={$catCode}&page={$i}'> {$i}</a></li>";
        }
```

Comment: Hmm... looks logical. I missed that part, too. Shame I didn't notice that earlier (so I could answer). :)